# How to Extract Elevation Data From GPX File

Tags: swift, xcode, parsing, gpx, elevation

In the app we are currently developing, users can import a GPX file. We parse that GPX file and extract the coordinates so we can display the route on the map.

However, the GPX file also has elevation data (ele) but I can't figure out how to extract each of the elevation values.

Rather than post the entire GPX file, here is a few short lines showing the coordinates and elevation value:

```
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="51.47777000000001" lon="-0.9179800000000001">
<ele>35.85</ele>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.47795000000001" lon="-0.9184300000000001">
<ele>35.85</ele>
</trkpt>
```

To parse the GPX file this is the code being used:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    
    if elementName == "trkpt" || elementName == "wpt" || elementName == "rtept" {
        let lat = Double(attributeDict["lat"]!)
        let lon = Double(attributeDict["lon"]!)
        let coordinateData = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)
        coordinates.append(coordinateData)
    }
}
```

How is it possible to extract the elevation data and append to an array or similar?

Comment: You have to proceed to parse the track point node to reach the elevation node.

Comment: @matt This is the issue, I can't seem to get to the value. I have tried if elementName == "ele" but the value is always blank for some reason! I'm sure this has something to do with the fact it doesn't have a key like "lat" and "lon"

Comment: Might help to see more sophisticated parser: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch23p818xml/ch36p1070xml

Comment: In particular notice https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/c0186b6d8b3da7efa12f8d74e318bd359dd77df6/bk2ch23p818xml/ch36p1070xml/MyXMLParserDelegate.swift#L30 — you have to implement `foundCharacters` to get text node between tags

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this function of the Delegate:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
```

there you can retrieve what is between the start and end tag and just need to get the double coded in the string. Bare in mind, that if that text between is long you need to append together the strings, since it might be called several times for parts of it. In your case, with only the elevation numbers it should be fine ignoring that, but if you want to use it for more, take it into account.

It may also be necessary to save in the other function what kind of tag you are currently parsing, so that you don't parse data you don't need.

Comment: Thanks Jelumar. That's helped a little but I'm still a little lost. If I print the foundCharacterss string to the console there are plenty of what looks like empty strings with the elevation numbers inbetween. I thought it would be relatively easy to just grab the elevation values by doing a character count on the strings but even the empty strings are still printing as though characters exist. Does that make sense?

Comment: you can use string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) so you get only the character content of the string, and if then string.isEmpty you just ignore it.

Comment: But the thing that would helpt more I think is the following: in the function you used already for parsing of the attributes ("func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, name[...]") you add "currentTag = elementName" and you add "private currentTag: String = """ to the class. Then in the new function with the foundCharacters you only take the string into account when currentTag == "ele" so that only those content is used when you know it is inside an ele-tag where the elevation is stored.

Comment: Thanks Jelumar, that helped a lot. I think I should be able to do this now. I can't award the bounty for another 15 hours.

Comment: NP, I am happy if it helped, had a similar problem a month ago ;)

Comment: Yep all good, getting results exactly as expected. Thanks Jelumar ;-)

Comment: Hello @Chris, can you please share a little snippet how you get this to work? Iam also looking for the lat lon ele and name… but dont get it to work :(